# Spring AOP : Logging function not getting called via aspectJ, have attached the xml file below

Tags: spring, aop

Below is the XML file not sure why the function creditCardAmountBorrowedUpdation() is not getting called:

```xml
<aop:config>
  <aop:aspect id="beforeTransactions" ref="authorizeCCTransactionsLogs">
    <aop:pointcut
      expression="execution(void AuthorizeCCTransactions.CreditCardHelper.creditCardAmountBorrowedUpdation(..))"
      id="beforeDepositing"/>
    <aop:before method="beforeApprovingCCTransactions" pointcut-ref="beforeDepositing"/>
    <aop:after method="afterApprovingCCTransactions" pointcut-ref="beforeDepositing"/>
  </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow. You have missed adding the xm and other relevant details . Please share the aspect code , the target method and aop xml configurations

Comment: I edited your question, made the wrongly formatted XML snippet visible, reformatted it and added syntax highlighting. Please learn how to edit questions and next time do it yourself. It is quite sloppy to just post a question and not update it if you see for yourself that the XML you are asking about is not even being displayed. And as @R.G said, please provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not just a configuration snippet without aspect and application code. Thank you. Besides, the Java term for what you call a "function" is "method". ;-)